# Google Firebase FCM - registration token

Tags: java, android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use this Java class in order to send push notifications to device:

```
public class FirebaseServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements FirebaseService {

public FirebaseServiceImpl() {
}

@Override
public void initFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp("my-project-id");
    logger.info("firebase service initialized in FirebaseServiceImpl#initFirebase");
}

public void sendFirebaseMessage() {
    try {
        logger.info("send firebase message in FirebaseServiceImpl#sendFirebaseMessage");

        String registrationToken = "c4QGdbL_TTqZXaBC3F5qhD:APA91bGCk1GoLYCECE6UaX4rUtUEaDV1wZiRco_hKux2LQ7OY82-XKoxFLI19lzmRk2WWwEMAY--oluNfAM26A0oh7AE8zasel_AVjQYFqitDmxAufg-7fPl5-35vez5DT8iB78xOS8g"; // "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";

        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        Message message = Message.builder().putData("score", "850").putData("time", "2:45").setToken(registrationToken).build();

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        final FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("my-project-id");
        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app).send(message);
        logger.info("successfully sent firebase message with response '{}' in FirebaseServiceImpl#sendFirebaseMessage", response);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following exception:

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException.withMessagingErrorCode(FirebaseMessagingException.java:51)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl$MessagingErrorHandler.createException(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:293)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl$MessagingErrorHandler.createException(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:282)
at com.google.firebase.internal.AbstractHttpErrorHandler.handleHttpResponseException(AbstractHttpErrorHandler.java:57)
at com.google.firebase.internal.ErrorHandlingHttpClient.send(ErrorHandlingHttpClient.java:108)
at com.google.firebase.internal.ErrorHandlingHttpClient.sendAndParse(ErrorHandlingHttpClient.java:72)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendSingleRequest(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:127)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.send(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:113)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$1.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:137)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$1.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:134) 
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/levos-app/messages:send
{
 "error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
   }
 ]
 }
}
```

I got the registration token from my Angular (ionic) client installed at my Android mobile phone:

```
PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
 (token: Token) => {
   alert('Push registration success, token is: ' + token.value);
 })
```

My question now would be whether someone have any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A registration token can change a lot, when a user force closes the app, reboots the phone or when the operations systems wants so. Therefore retrieving it everytime the app boots is vital. Make sure that this is happening and try again